# How to clear the cookies of system safari in iOS

Tags: ios, cookies, safari

I am developing an app in iOS, and uses OAuth 2.0 to do authorizaiton. 
The app send a url request to open a authorization page in IOS DEFAULT SAFARI.
It remembers login status since I signed in once and I can't clear the cookies to logout.

Is there a programmatical way to clear the cookies of a certain website's cookies in the DEFAULT SAFARI?

I have tried this, but the array has 0 item.

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSArray *cookies = [cookieStorage cookies];
```